# apigee using Synchronous XMLHttpRequest

Tags: apigee

When I run [apigee's first JavaScript example](http://docs.apigee.com/api-baas/content/sdks#javascript), I get:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Q: Why would they be using a synchronous XMLHttpRequest? Is this first example outdated?